# ruby select inner hash from nested hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I need to filter a nested hash to return items for a particular combination of attributes. If the attribute is present it returns that hash, if the attribute is not present it returns the default. If the attribute is set to 'none' it returns nothing. Consider the following hash:

```
{
  "size"=>{
    "default"=>{
      "jeans"=>"boyfriend"
     }, 
   "blue"=>"none"
 }, 
 "style"=>{
   "default"=>{
     "shoes"=>"boots"
    },
   "blue"=>{
     "jeans"=>"jeggings"
    }
  }
}
```

if the color is 'black', then

```
{
  "size"=>{
    "jeans"=>"boyfriend"
  }, 
  "style"=>{
    "shoes"=>"boots"
  }
}
```

or if the color is 'blue', then

```
{
  "size"=>{
  }, 
  "style"=>{
    "jeans"=>"jeggings"
  }
}
```

What is best way to do this? I have tried various combinations of select and delete but either end up with an array or a hash with the color key included.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of you code?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: "What is best way to do this?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: @JörgWMittag fair comment, but maybe a little overkill

Answer (score 0):

Letting `h` be the hash given in the question, the following method will return the desired hash if my understanding of the question is correct.

```
def doit(h, color)
  h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,f),g|
    c,v = f.find { |kk,_| kk != "default" }
    if c == color
      g[k] = v.is_a?(Hash) ? v : {}
    else
      g[k] = f["default"]
    end
  end
end

doit(h, 'black')
  #=> {"size"=>{"jeans"=>"boyfriend"}, "style"=>{"shoes"=>"boots"}}
doit(h, 'blue')
  #=> {"size"=>{}, "style"=>{"jeans"=>"jeggings"}}
```

The steps for the second example are as follows.

```
color = 'blue'

enum = h.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: {"size"=>{"default"=>{"jeans"=>"boyfriend"},
  #     "blue"=>"none"}, "style"=>{"default"=>{"shoes"=>"boots"},
  #     "blue"=>{"jeans"=>"jeggings"}}}:each_with_object({})>
```

The first value of this enumerator is generated:

```
x = enum.next
  #=> [["size", {"default"=>{"jeans"=>"boyfriend"}, "blue"=>"none"}], {}]
```

and passed to the block. The block variables are set equal to `x` and their values are determined by "disambiguation":

```
(k,f),g = x
k #=> "size"
f ##=> {"default"=>{"jeans"=>"boyfriend"}, "blue"=>"none"}
g #=> {}
```

The block calculation is now performed.

```
c,v = f.find { |kk,_| kk != "default" }
  #=> ["blue", "none"]
c #=> "blue"
v #=> "none"
```

As

```
c == color
  #=> "blue" == "blue" => true
```

we compute

```
v.is_a?(Hash)
  #=> false
```

and therefore perform the assignment

```
g[k] = {}
  #=> {}
```

so that now

```
g #=> {"size"=>{}}
```

The second and last element of `h` is now generated and passed to the block.

```
x = enum.next
  #=> [["style", {"default"=>{"shoes"=>"boots"},
  #     "blue"=>{"jeans"=>"jeggings"}}], {"style"=>{"jeans"=>"jeggings"}}]
(k,f),g = x
k #=> "style"
f #=> {"default"=>{"shoes"=>"boots"}, "blue"=>{"jeans"=>"jeggings"}}
g #=> {"size"=>"none"}
c,v = f.find { |kk,_| kk != "default" }
  #=> ["blue", {"jeans"=>"jeggings"}]
c #=> "blue"
v #=> {"jeans"=>"jeggings"}
c == color
  # "blue" == "blue" => true
v.is_a?(Hash)
  #=> true
g[k] = v
  #=> {"jeans"=>"jeggings"}
g #=> {"size"=>"none", "style"=>{"jeans"=>"jeggings"}}
```

and `g` is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and a nice approach using each_with_object. I'll experiment with that.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I ended up with after some refactoring. It works and tests all pass. Could do with more refactoring.

```
class Filterer
  def self.filter(facets, color)
    acc = {}
    facets.each do |k, facets|
      facets.each do |_, facet|
        acc[k] = color_facets(color, facets)  
      end
    end

    acc
  end

  def self.color_facets(color, facets)
    return {} if no_facets?(color, facets)

    facets[color] ? facets[color] : facets['default']
  end

  def self.no_facets?(color, facets)
    facets[color] && facets[color] == 'no facet'
  end
end
```